# Asymptotics of sequence depending on Tricomi's function

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I'm dealing with the following sequence
$$ p_n = U(a, a - n, 1)$$
where $a > 0$ and $U$ is [Tricomi's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer.27s_equation).
I suspect that asymptotically when $n \to \infty$ its behaviour is a power law ([evidence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log-linear%20plot%20log%28U%282.5%20,%202.5%20-%20x,%201%29%29%20vs%20-2.5%20log%28x%29%20%20,%20x=%201%20to%20100000))
$$ p_n \sim 1/n^a $$
but I cannot arrive to anything with known properties (I've already checked the NIST handbook).
Any ideas are welcome, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Found stronger evidence: $\beta=a$

**EDIT**: Specified which asymptote

Comment: I assume you're interested in the behavior when $n \to \infty$.  By applying the Laplace method to the integral representation $13.2.5$ in [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_505.htm) I get that $$U(a,a-n,1) \sim \frac{1}{n^a}$$ if $0 < a \leq 1$ and $$U(a,a-n,1) \sim \frac{e^{1-a}}{\Gamma(a)} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a-1}} \left(\frac{a-1}{n}\right)^a$$ if $a > 1$.  It's a little late now to type up the workings so I will post a complete answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to work it out in the meantime

Comment: I'm still struggling to apply the method. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some details in the following derivation which will be omitted to keep this answer at a reasonable length.  What follows is a set of clotheslines on which a rigorous proof can hopefully be hung.

We will use the integral representation

$$
\begin{align}
U(a,a-n,1) &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)} \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{a-1} (1+t)^{-n-1}\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)} \int_0^\infty \exp f_{a,n}(t)\,dt.
\end{align}
$$

(see [equation 13.2.5 in Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_505.htm)).  The function $f_{a,n}(t)$ critical points at $t \approx -n$ and $t \approx \frac{a-1}{n}$, so in the domain of integration the function will be maximized at $t=0$ if $a>1$ for $n$ large enough.  One can check explicitly that this is also true when $a=1$.  If $a>1$ then $f_{a,n}(t)$ is maximized at the point $t \approx \frac{a-1}{n}$.

Let's consider the case $0 < a \leq 1$.  We have

$$
\begin{align}
f_{a,n}(t) &= -t + (a-1)\log t - (n+1)\log(1+t) \\
&= -t + (a-1)\log t - (n+1)t + O(nt^2) \\
&\approx (a-1)\log t - (n+2)t,
\end{align}
$$

near $t=0$, so that as $n \to \infty$ the Laplace method yields

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \exp f_{a,n}(t)\,dt &\sim \int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl[(a-1)\log t - (n+2)t\Bigr]\,dt \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(a)}{(n+2)^a} \\
&\sim \frac{\Gamma(a)}{n^a}.
\end{align}
$$

Now let's consider $a>1$.  In this case the function $f_{a,n}(t)$ has a maximum inside the range of integration at $t = t^* \approx \frac{a-1}{n}$.  Explicitly this is

$$
\begin{align}
t^* &= \frac{-n+a-3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n^2+(-2a+6)n+a^2-2a+5} \\
&= \frac{-n+a-3}{2}+\frac{n}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{-2a+6}{n}+\frac{a^2-2a+5}{n^2}} \\
&= \frac{-n+a-3}{2}+\frac{n}{2}\left[1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-2a+6}{n}+\frac{a^2-2a+5}{n^2}\right) \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad \left.- \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{-2a+6}{n}+\frac{a^2-2a+5}{n^2}\right)^2 + O\left(\frac{1} {n^3}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{-n+a-3}{2}+\frac{n}{2}\left[1 + \frac{-a+3}{n} + \frac{2a-2}{n^2} + O\left(\frac{1} {n^3}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{-n+a-3}{2} + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{-a+3}{2} + \frac{a-1}{n} + O\left(\frac{1} {n^2}\right) \\
&= \frac{a-1}{n} + O\left(\frac{1} {n^2}\right),
\end{align}
$$

where we used the fact that $\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8} + O(x^3)$ to get the third equality.  We then have

$$
\begin{align}
f_{a,n}(t) &= -t + (a-1)\log t - (n+1)\log(1+t) \\
&= \alpha(a,n) + \beta(a,n)(t-t^*)^2 + \text{higher order terms},
\end{align}
$$

and we calculate

$$
\alpha(a,n) = (a-1)\Bigl[\log(a-1)-\log(n)-1\Bigr] + o(1)
$$

and

$$
\beta(a,n) = -\frac{n^2}{2 (a-1)} + O(n).
$$

By the Laplace method we conclude that

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \exp f_{a,n}(t)\,dt &\sim e^{\alpha(a,n)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\Bigl[ \beta(a,n) t^2 \Bigr]\,dt \\
&\sim \exp\Bigl\{(a-1)\Bigl[\log(a-1)-\log(n)-1\Bigr]\Bigr\} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\Bigl[ -\frac{n^2}{2 (a-1)} t^2 \Bigr]\,dt \\
&= e^{1-a} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a-1}} \left(\frac{a-1}{n}\right)^a.
\end{align}
$$

In summary,

> If $0 < a \leq 1$ then
>   $$
> U(a,a-n,1) \sim \frac{1}{n^a}
> $$
>   and if $a > 1$ then
>   $$
> U(a,a-n,1) \sim \frac{e^{1-a}}{\Gamma(a)} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a-1}} \left(\frac{a-1}{n}\right)^a.
> $$

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. Just one doubt, I can't see why $t^* \approx (a-1)/n$

Comment: I can check it empirically though.

Comment: You're very welcome.  I've added the steps in the derivation of the approximation for $t^*$ and corrected a typo in it.

Comment: Thanks again. Very clever!